# React-Native NetInfo dosen't work after once did work?

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-native-community-netinfo

I'm new at react-native I have a problem about internet connection check. When I open my app and disconnect for internet(wifi or cellular both) I got a alert message that's what I want. But when I connect again to internet and try again I see in my console state is again false. NO way to see true. Where did I do a fault?

```
` const [isInternetReachable, setInternetReachable] = useState(true)

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = NetInfo.addEventListener(state => { 
      if (!(state.isInternetReachable === null)) {
        setInternetReachable(state.isInternetReachable);
      }
    });
  },[])

  useEffect(() => {
    chechConnection();
 }, [isInternetReachable]);

  const chechConnection = () => {
    if(isInternetReachable === false) {
      Alert.alert(
        'Internet fail',
        'Try again.',
        [
          {text: 'Try Again', onPress: chechConnection},
          {text: 'Exit', onPress:() => RNExitApp.exitApp()},
        ],
        { cancelable: false }
      )
    }
  };`
```

Answer (score 0):

The useEffect which is responsible for `setInternetReachable` will only run once, no matter what.

Try like this:

```
  const [connected, setConnected] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = NetInfo.addEventListener((state) => {
      console.log("Connection type", state.type);

      console.log("Is Internet Reachable?", state.isInternetReachable);

      if (connected !== state.isInternetReachable)
        setConnected(state.isInternetReachable);
    });

    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, [connected]);
```

Comment: Actulay that doesn't work. Thanks for your help. I found a problem its when I use İf condition or switch my connection state doesn't work. I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: It definitly works. I use it by myself. Fault must be on your side

Answer (score 0):

I found a problem its when I use İf condition or switch my connection state doesn't change. When I don't use switch or if connection state works well.